# this.context.toggle is not a function

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I 'm working on a react project and just trying to use " reactstrap " dropDown menu but suddenly I 'm facing this problem of " this.context.toggle is not a function " any ideas of how to avoid it ?

Comment: Can you post the relevant component?

Comment: `import React,{Component} from "react";
import { 
  Dropdown, 
  DropdownToggle, 
  DropdownMenu, 
  DropdownItem 
 } from 'reactstrap';



class ProfileIcon extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
   dropdownOpen : false 
  };
 }

 toggle = () => {
     this.setState(prevState => ({
       dropdownOpen: !prevState.dropdownOpen
     }));
   }`

Comment: [you will find my full formatted, organized code here](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/album?album_id=5613916207)

Comment: Can u move it to codesandbox?  This site requires registration

Comment: yea sure [you can find it here] (https://codesandbox.io/s/r792jovk44)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get this to work this way.  I don't know why yours isn't working

```
import React from 'react';
import { UncontrolledDropdown, DropdownToggle, DropdownMenu, DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';

export default class Example extends React.Component {
  render(){
  return (
    <UncontrolledDropdown>
      <DropdownToggle caret>
        Dropdown
      </DropdownToggle>
      <DropdownMenu>
        <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem disabled>Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
        <DropdownItem divider />
        <DropdownItem>Another Action</DropdownItem>
      </DropdownMenu>
    </UncontrolledDropdown>
  );}
}


Versions:

      "dependencies": {
        "react": "16.8.6",
        "react-dom": "16.8.6",
        "reactstrap": "8.0.0"
      },
```

With the version you are using you can use uncontrolled, this won't require state

Comment: may be all I need is to update react I will try updating it and then check again

Comment: my Versions are
    `"react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2" ,
  "reactstrap": "^8.0.0",
 `

Comment: I guess that my versions are more updated than you , 
any way thank you so much for your time

Comment: Updated to use an uncontrolled no state component.

Comment: guess what ! 
I 'm facing the same problem here

Comment: ok let's just say that the problem is in calling the toggle function not in the function it self but we need to know what does this.context mean ?

Comment: I think now it's about isOpen function because I have tried to pass down true as a value to it and guess what it didn't worked !

Comment: @Iakerskill but how the uncontrolled drop-down button gives me an a state error ?!

Answer (score 0):

It's actually that my react was updated to the latest version right now which is 18.8.6 and my react-dom package wasn't updated so this occurred so as soon as I updated it every thing worked just fine so I hope it does for you to.

Comment: I know you're excited, but please try to keep your language under control. Think of Stack Overflow as more like Wikipedia than like Reddit.

Answer (score 0):

Updating react and react-dom worked for me.